# wp_enqueue_style and different styles for blog template

Tags: templates, page-template, blog

I have a `front-page.php` to create the index page template and a `page-blog.php` to create the blog template. My styles are added using `wp_enqueue_style` in my `functions.php`, but I'd like to use different items (css and js) on `page-blog.php`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using hooks such as [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) you have access to [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags). This allows you to only enqueue certain things on certain pages, templates, taxonomies, etc.

By default, WordPress accepts two template files as the natural blog:

1. `index.php`
2. `home.php`

You can read more about this in the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#home-page-display) post, while it does say "Home" this will only take the place of the homepage if `front-page.php` does not exist in your theme. What you have is a [Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#page) as your "Blog" and **not the standard** you need to use `is_page()`:

```
/**
 * Enqueue Styles and Scripts
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    if( is_page( 'blog' ) ) {   // Only add this style onto the Blog page.
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Comment: if I use home.php to define my blog, instead of the page-blog template, and have front-page.php for my actual Index page, what will be the url for the blog?

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira In the WordPress Admin - If you have a Page called "Home" and a Page called "Blog" and have 2 template: `front-page.php` and `home.php`. Then in the admin you set under `Settings -> Reading` "Home" as the Front Page and "Blog" as Posts Page your "Home" page content will show up using the `front-page.php` template and your blog page will use `home.php`. The url for "Blog" is the slug, so in this case `www.domain.com/blog/`. If you created a page "Something" and assigned it under `Settings -> Reading` as the Posts Page, your blog would be `www.domain.com/something/`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a conditional based on the page template.

```
if ( is_page_template( 'page-blog.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet_name' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script_name' );
}
```